# Turtle graphics on Wakari?

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I'm experimenting with Python running in Wakari.io, and I tried to do some turtle graphics, just to see if that module would work. From this code

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Pen()
t.forward(50)
```

I got the following error messages:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-c761d5a63f4f> in <module>()
----> 1 import turtle
      2 t = turtle.Pen()
      3 t.forward(50)

/opt/anaconda/envs/np18py27-1.9/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py in <module>()
    105 #print _ver
    106 
--> 107 import Tkinter as TK
    108 import types
    109 import math

/opt/anaconda/envs/np18py27-1.9/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py in <module>()
     37     # Attempt to configure Tcl/Tk without requiring PATH
     38     import FixTk
---> 39 import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
     40 tkinter = _tkinter # b/w compat for export
     41 TclError = _tkinter.TclError

ImportError: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I make this code work? .. thanks!

Comment: Do you have X11 installed?

Comment: Err... I don't think the the turtle package is really designed to be used for anything except playing around on your local computer. As you can see it's trying to connect to an X11 server, which is unlikely to work on "Wakari".